# Properly create a RAML 1.0 Named Example

Tags: rest, mulesoft, raml

I am using RAML 1.0 to specify an API, but having trouble working with the Named Example fragment type. I've looked at numerous tutorials and examples, but cannot find a definitive guide to what's expected in this resource.

I'm working with the MuleSoft Anypoint Platform API Designer. (May 2020)

Here is my DataType definition:

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
type: object
properties:
  display-name: 
    required: true
    type: string
  note-properties:
    required: true
    type: object
  note-data:
    required: true
    type: any
```

Here is my Named Example fragment:

```
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
noteExample:
    display-name: greeting
    note-properties: read-only
    note-data: Hello world
```

And here is the root file that references these:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: sandbox API

types:
  noteType: !include definitions/noteType.raml

/note:
  get:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: noteType
            examples: !include examples/noteExample.raml
```

The issue is that the parser (APIKit plugin) reports this as an error.  Here is the error message from Design Center:

> ['note-properties'] should be object at /examples/noteExample.raml (3, 1)

I've also tried a simpler DataType definition, but I get the same error.

Is there an obvious error in my Named Example file. I know there must be a definitive spec, but so far what I find are various (occasionally conflicting) examples.

Comment: ...it turns out that if I read it more slowly, and after having tried some unsuccessful things, that this page (https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-named-examples) helped a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...okay, this is embarrassing. The error message tells exactly what is wrong.

It clearly says "XXX should be an object"

When I changed the Named Example to this:

```
#%RAML 1.0 NamedExample
noteExample:
  type: object
  properties:
    status: read-only
    note-data: Hello world
```

...where the value presented for

> note-properties

is an actual object instead of a simple string (as it was in my OP), then that worked just fine.

Comment: If the get returns list of note example, Is there anyway to denote array of noteExample in examples?

Comment: ...it turns out that, yes there is! I found myself back here 15 months after the OP, looking for the answer this post contains. Clearly, there is an even better way to solve this, and it deserves another node! And your question @BenTennyson, is an excellent reason for having it.